# i can't find the organisation i created in amazon work mails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, amazon-workmail

I created an organisation of work mails first and then also created another one after sometime. I am now looking for the first organisation to do some edits on a certain email but I cant find the organisation. I only see the one I created last. the emails in the first organisation still work but I do not see where to edit them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can I suggest to OP and any future Googlers out there; if you're having trouble finding an organization you created, try switching the AWS Region to find the missing Organization. I've personally encountered this same issue of not being able to find an Org I created.